# Pros and Cons of using DNN and CNN in both image classification and object recognition

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, tracking, object-recognition

I totally agree the CNN has been used as the basic structure of R-CNN, Fact R-CNN, and YOLO.

My question is that if we have **big enough data**, is it still good to use DNN? If not so, what is the negative side of using DNN?

How about object recognition in the case of **small image datasets**? Do you prefer to use DNN or CNN?

Comment: DNN or CNN? what do you mean? CNN is like a subclass of DNN

Comment: It is true somehow. I was asked this in an interviewing process.

Comment: Confusing interview. Especially about the object recognition one, ofc you are going to use CNN (which is also DNN)